# Timer runs too quickly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried making an automatic slideshow with buttons to click. The slideshow does work but when I click one of the buttons my slideshow will trip and go way faster then it should.

Here is what I tried.

```html
<script>
  var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;

    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 10 seconds
  }
</script>
```

Why does my slideshow trip whenever I click my onclick button?

This is the HTML

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="button button1" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
  <span class="button button2" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="button button3" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
</div>

<!--Slideshow images-->
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides Fade">
    <img src="homeScreen/teslaRoadster.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="centered-text"> Customize Your Own Car</div>
    <button class="btnCustom">
      <a id="costumLink" href="#custom">Customize</a>
    </button>

  </div>

  <div class="mySlides Fade">
    <img src="homeScreen/modelXHomeScreen.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="top-left"> MODEL X</div>
    <button class="btnModelX">
      <a id="costumLink" href="#modelx">Order Now</a>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides Fade">
    <img src="homeScreen/cybertruckHomeScreen.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="centered-text">The Future Is Now</div>
    <button class="btnCyberTruck">
      <a id="costumLink" href="#cybertruck">Order Now</a>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `5000); // Change image every 10 seconds` <--- that is every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `showSlides()` function starts a timer each time it's invoked and that timer, in turn calls `showSlides()` again, you wind up "stacking" up calls for the function that run one right after the other.

What you need to do is set up a variable reference to the timer and, before starting a new timer, make sure the previous one has been stopped by using `clearTimeout()` as shown below. This will ensure that you never have more than a single timer in the queue.

```
var timer = null; // Will hold reference to timer

function showSlides() {

  // Clear any running timer
  clearTimeout(timer);

  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;

  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  timer = setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Get reference to timer
}
```